# i have massive attack on port in my server

Tags: server, 15.04, security, iptables, firewall

i have Ubuntu 15.4 server i open a port with number 20000 i got massive ddos attack on this port i typed in terminal

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

to catch the attacker ip and block it i found bazillion ip's with opened connection 55

i need to create automatic script using iptables  to protect that port

so if ip have connection more than 5 iptable block it automatically using

```
iptables -A INPUT -s attacker ip address -j DROP
```

but i dont know how to do that script it will take forever to block the ips one by one  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will detect the IPs and then drop them for more than a day.

```
# Dynamic Badguy List. Detect and DROP Bad IPs that try to access port 20000.
# Once they are on the BADGUY list then DROP all packets from them.

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --update --hitcount 5 --seconds 90000 --name BADGUY -j LOG --log-prefix "Port 20000 BAD:" --log-level info
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --update --hitcount 5 --seconds 90000 --name BADGUY -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20000 -m recent --set --name BADGUY -j ACCEPT
```

Replace `eth0` with your actual interface name.
Place these rules **after** your ESTABLISHED,RELATED by-pass rule. A typical example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: i just add the rules ? or i have run them with cron job ?

Comment: Just add the rules.

Comment: i have main eth0 and other ip failover with eth0:0 and eth0:1 can i apply this rules on all of them ?

Comment: You can not apply iptables rules using aliased interface names. So, I would guess that you would apply somehow using `eth0`.

Comment: i added this rule first `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`   then added the rest rules i see attack reduced

Comment: If you are getting too many log entries, then you can delete the logging rule. I have the logging rule because I study this stuff.

Comment: is this working on new connection too ?

Comment: Once the hitcount has been triggered, yes it works on all subsequent NEW connections.